# Absolute value : Freshman exercise

Tags: inequality

Prove that each of the group R :

$$|x+y| \leq\ |x| +  |y|$$

Of course I'm not a lazy person I tried solving before since the teacher gave this exercise to us in the  exam. I wanted to know the right answer because we still haven't corrected the test.

Thanks and Sorry for any faults. This is my first question in this website. How would I know if it's duplicate?

Comment: What is \langle?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ have the same sign then you have equality. What happens if they have opposite signs?

Comment: We don't know the signs of x and y It can be both positive and negative

Comment: @ManalBouabdallaoui : I think Ian is suggesting that you examine separate cases depending on the signs of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I think Ian is suggesting that you consider that case explicitly and see what happens if $x$ is positive and $y$ is negative (or *vice versa*).

Comment: @JoelCohen: Ha!

Comment: Isn't this just the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both sides are non-negative numbers, it is the same to prove
\begin{align*}
\lvert x+y\rvert^2\le(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert)^2&\iff (x+y)^2\le x^2+y^2+2\lvert x\rvert\,\lvert y\rvert\\&\iff 2xy\le 2\lvert x\rvert\,\lvert y\rvert\iff xy\le\lvert xy\rvert
\end{align*}

(We used  $\lvert x\rvert^2=x^2$).

Comment: This answer contains more logic for my question I have to try it again to see if I well understood.

Answer (score 4):

If $x+y\geq0$ then
$$|x+y|=x+y\leq|x|+|y|.$$
If $x+y<0$ then
$$|x+y|=-x-y\leq|x|+|y|.$$

Comment: A remark on the second case: you have $-x-y=(-x)+(-y) \leq |-x|+|-y|=|x|+|y|$. (It took me a moment to catch this.)

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to square it :

$$|x|+|y| \geq |x+y|$$ 
if and only if :

$$(|x|+|y|)^2 \geq (x+y)^2$$
$$x^2+2|xy|+y^2 \geq x^2+2xy+y^2$$

$$2|xy| \geq 2xy$$ but this is obvious .

Comment: Thank you I will try all the possible answers